# My code works for only one input. Please advice

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in c++ problems.I was trying to attempt the problem where we determine whether the number is perfect or not. My code only seems to work for one number which is 6. For all the rest it fails like number 28. I cannot find where I am going wrong. Please Advice

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int sum = 1;

    cout<<"enter a number : " <<endl;
    cin>>n;

    for(int i =2;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        if(n%i != 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
    }

    if(sum == n)
    {
        cout<<"Perfect Number"<<endl;

    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Not a perfect number"<<endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the line that says `break` and I think it works. Not sure why you thought `break` was a good idea as it ends the loop. Why would you want to end the loop before you've considered all the numbers?

Comment: Time to learn [how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, to figure out, where the code starts doing something you didn't expect? For instance, once your code encounters some number, that isn't a factor of the number, that you are checking - it just stops, instead of adding all of the factors.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind breaking when you find a number that’s not a divisor of `n`? With 28, you will break at 3.

Comment: Why not `if(n%i == 0) sum=sum+i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
for(int i =2;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        if(n%i != 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
    }
```

With `break` you are stopping the whole iteration of you `for` loop, meaning after the first number which is not a divisor, i.e. where `n%i != 0` equals true you are breaking out of the loop and continue execution with `if(sum == n)`. I guess you where mistaken that as you don't want to add `i`s which are not a divisor, you where too "eager" not to count them. I guess you mixed it up with `continue` which would had gone back to the `for` condition check and would have continued execution with `i+1` if the condition is still true.

Still as you had packed the addition in an `else` branch, meaning the summation would either way only happen if and only the `if` before `n%i != 0` would be false, meaning if its a divisor. Thats the reason you don't need either `continue`, which would not do any big difference, nor `break`, which "breaks" you program in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped a lot. So,if I was to optimize the code,then I should remove the else loop and use 'continue' in the if loop?

Comment: Yes you could remove the else and the brackets but you still would need the addition after the continue in the for loop body

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes those are are conditional statements and not loops. Will remember to use exact terminologies from now. In habit I keep refering them as loops which is a very grave mistake on my part.